# How can I ssh without a password

Tags: macos, ssh, passwords

My os is OS X 10.8.5. I want to ssh to localhost, but I always get prompted for a password.I don't know the password.

How do I reset the ssh config in mac osx? I removed .ssh folder.

Answer (score 0):

ssh does not work without a password, it would compromise your system too much.
You may setup an easy password for youself and use the command "sudo ssh username@127.0.0.1" then you will be prompted for the password you usualy are using.

You also may enable the root account and use this account. But be carefull, you can mess up you system pretty much when you are logged in as a root user.
Enable root user via path "Your hard disk"/System/Library/CoreServices. There you find al lot of handy programs for system management. You be looking for the "Directory utility" App.
After starting this App unlock the lock (left below) and fill in your system password.
Then via the menu at the top you can unlock the root user, via (Edit/Enable root user). Choose then a password. If you fill in no password then the root user will not be enabled, i think.

Hope this will help you.